# Best way to deal with big (shape-)data for map in Android Application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-fusion-tables, openstreetmap, shapefile

I am building the prototype for an Android app that should result in a versatile map that can deal with a large but static amount of environmental data combined with (user-generated) data that will be hosted on a separate platform. 
My current approach is to fetch the large static data via Google Fusion Tables (in original a shape file - .shp, .dbf, .shx that I have exported as a .kml with QGisMaps - the "smaller" .kml I am using is already 66.4MB, the one intended for final use over 140 MB...) I know it is possible to slice down .kml but will this have an effect on loading times?
You can see a current example of the shape data on Google Maps here https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S717313eWaJ

But now I am wondering if I am on the right path at all since this one layer of data is loading very slowly on my machine and I am not aware of the hassle to put this map into an Android app - and more importantly also fetching more data from a separate server and putting it as another (filterable) layer on top of it. This layer will be collected data from users, thus not "static" but regularly updated - integer values displayed in color per geodata.

Several people hinted me to use Open Street Maps but some advised that Android is very eloquent with Google Maps - in the middle of development I thought maybe someone can tell me whether I chose the right direction to go for or are most likely facing less problems with an alternative solution.

I would be really glad if someone could advise me on the issue with combining map data from two different sources layerd onto one map in Android whereas one bunch of data is huge but static and the other user-generated values.

Thanks so much for your time and looking over this

best
Birgit

EDIT #1: I am now switching to Open Street Maps, hoping to be able to set up a GeoServer myself hosting the data and querying the WMS with the App. It seems like the size of the data still has to be compressed in some way, I will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I eventually converted a .shp file into a format that could be displayed by OSMdroid's XYTilesource.

I exported the layers separately as .kml projected WGS84 and imported them as layers to TileMill.  After having defied the colors for each layer in CSS, I exported my map as a set of MBTiles. I uploaded them to Mapbox.com. From there I can fetch the tiles which are in the format a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/myUsername.myTiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png in my OSMdroid Mapview.

```
final myTileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("myTiles", null, 10, 16, 256, ".png", "http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/myUserName.myTiles/");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll not be able to address all of your concernes, but I can share some of my experience with maps and ovelays.

The most important concept you must be aware is the `memory heap`. Each android application has a maximum memory amount that can be used to allocate data objects, called `memory heap`. This limit is different from device to device and can go from 16MB in small older devices to 64MB in new tablets.

Having said that, you will never be able to load all your data at one shot if the data structure required to hold it exceeds the maximum heap available for the application.

Also, usaging large amounts of memory makes your application better candidate to be terminated by users or by the SO when additional memory is required by critical activities (like a phone call).

**Now, going to the maps part...**

I've used Google maps as well as mapsforge api for OpenStreet maps. Google maps requires internet connection, while mapsforge enables you to use a local map file or online connection. OpenStree maps don't provide the sattelite view.

Regarding performance, online connection tends to be faster, as they download already rendered map images, while offline map requires the images to be rendered as needed. Mapforges can use a local cache to improve this a little.

**Displaying Overlays:**

I've used both API's to display paths with arround 10.000 points over a map, together with additional overlays (compass, scale bar, pop-ups, etc.) and the code runs smoothly in a mid-rande device. However, my code have some optimizations to reduce recreation of paths (when user zoom or move map) by transforming the already existing path.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. If you had any useful links to examples/tutorials on how to use maps from fusiontables in an app I would be very grateful. As a start I'd just need the map from the above link with GPS functionality but it is very hard to find well explained Android-fusion-table examples online.

Comment: @birgit I've never used fusion tables, so I'm afraid I'll not be able to help you with it specifically. You can find in this link: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html a good tutorial on how to create a simple android application that displays a map and some additional information in overlays. Let me know if you have trouble with it.